# Disable hover for a button using css class

Tags: css, hover

I need to disable the mouse hover on a particular button(not on all buttons) in the entire DOM.
Please let me know how to achieve it using a CSS class.

i am using the below CSS class when my button is disabled. now i want to remove the hover effect using the same class.

```
.buttonDisabled {
 Cursor:text !important; Text-Decoration: None !important; 
 }
```

The above class will take care of removing the hand sign and text underline on mouse over . Now i want to remove the text higlight as well

Comment: *Please let me know* what you have done so far

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Without more info, a base guess would be to assign that element a class that has no hover function.

Comment: @LcSalazar : i am using the below CSS class when my button is disabled. now i want to remove the hover effect using the same class.

.buttonDisabled
{
Cursor:text !important;
Text-Decoration: None !important;
}

The above class will take care of removing the hand sign and text underline on mouse over . Now i want to remove the text higlight as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").unbind("mouseover mouseout");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Avoid guessing in answers... The OP didn't provide enough informations for us to give an accurate answer. For example, how do you know that he meant JQuery, it's not even tagged. Maybe the hover is css-only. That's why we should ask for more info.

Comment: @LcSalazar : i am using the below CSS class when my button is disabled. now i want to remove the hover effect using the same class.

.buttonDisabled
{
Cursor:text !important;
Text-Decoration: None !important;
}

The above class will take care of removing the hand sign and text underline on mouse over . Now i want to remove the text higlight as well.

Answer (score 0):

use `removeClass('hover')`with a class to that only belongs your button.

Comment: Avoid guessing in answers... The OP didn't provide enough informations for us to give an accurate answer. For example, how do you know that he meant JQuery, it's not even tagged. Maybe the hover is css-only. That's why we should ask for more info.

Comment: @LcSalazar : i am using the below CSS class when my button is disabled. now i want to remove the hover effect using the same class. 
.buttonDisabled 
{ Cursor:text !important; 
Text-Decoration: None !important; } 
The above class will take care of removing the hand sign and text underline on mouse over . Now i want to remove the text higlight as well

Comment: @user2681868 - Then you should describe this on your question, as detailed as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are after is for styling purposes, I would recommend taking the initial hover class and altering it so that for the particular button the attributes stay exactly the same, which will give you the fastest results - performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out what the class of the button is.

Example:
This button has hover effects

Your CSS would be:
.hoverOn:hover { color:
background:
border:
}

Basically, set the color, background, border, and whatever there is back to what the button looks like originally.

Alternatively, search through your CSS and look for the :hover styles and remove them.